# Turing Machine - automata

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I am trying to find TM for $L = \{a^mb^nc^{m+n}: m \geq 0$ and $n \geq 0 \}$

This is what I have tried out so far. But as you see it generates some strings which are not in the language like acbc

[image]

I am stuck on how to improve my solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe this video would help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st65cJH1QBc

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have a TM, you can check the input before starting to make sure it's of the general form $\mathtt{a}^i\mathtt{b}^j\mathtt{c}^k$ and reject otherwise.

Second, this language is actually context-free, so it can be recognized by a simpler machine than a TM (though a TM will also work.)  It can be generated by  the context-free grammar $$S\mapsto \mathtt{a}S\mathtt{c} \;|\; T\qquad T\mapsto \mathtt{b}T\mathtt{c} \;|\; \epsilon$$